# Is there a way in C# to know DocuSign API calls limit?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to monitor DocuSign API calls limit programmatically. I was wondering if there's a way to do that in C#.

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is, but it's not an obvious way.

you need to analyze the response headers coming from the http calls.

```
ApiResponse<EnvelopeSummary> results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeWithHttpInfo(accountId, envelopeDefinition);results.Headers.TryGetValue("X-RateLimit-Remaining", out string remaining);
ApiResponse<EnvelopeSummary> results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeWithHttpInfo(accountId, envelopeDefinition);
results.Headers.TryGetValue("X-RateLimit-Reset", out string reset);
Console.WriteLine("API calls remaining: " + remaining);
Console.WriteLine("Next Reset: " + reset); // Unix timestamp
```

More details in this blog post - https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-from-the-trenches-working-with-headers-in-docusign-sdks/

(I assumed you mean real-time value, not the account level setting. You can also get the latter, let me know)